# How to parse configuration options from conf file in boolean format in python automatically?

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, python-3.x, configuration-files

Assume that a I have such configuration options under **[Bulutkare]** section:

```
[Bulutkare]
title = www.bulutkare.com
subtitle = www.bulutkare.com
id = 127
web_site = www.bulutkare.com
boolean_option = True
```

How can I parse ***boolean_option*** row as a boolean variable in my python module **AUTOMATICALLY**? I know, it can be parsed by using such code:

```
boolean_opt = config_parser.get("Bulutkare", "boolean_option")
```

but boolean_opt takes the option as String. My question is "how can my python code automatically recognize this option is a boolean?". So, my code can initialize **boolean_opt** as a boolean variable.

Is that possible?

Comment: `getboolean` should be what you want? https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.getboolean

Comment: this is not what ı am asking. in this example you know "boolean_option" is boolean. In my question, I don't know that boolean_option is a boolean or not. Code must recognize it. Not me. anyway thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `getboolean` method:

```
boolean_opt = config_parser.getboolean("Bulutkare", "boolean_option")
```

If you cannot have consistent type of the config option you can wrap the `get` call like that:

```
def get_boolean_or_string(option):
    if option == 'True':
        return True
    elif option == 'False':
        return False
    else:
        return option

boolean_opt = get_boolean_or_string(config_parser.get("Bulutkare", "boolean_option"))
```

If you don't mind importing `ast`:

```
import ast

def get_boolean_or_string(option):
    try:
        return ast.literal_eval(option)
    except ValueError:
        return option

boolean_opt = get_boolean_or_string(config_parser.get("Bulutkare", "boolean_option"))
```

Comment: this is  not what ı am asking. in this example you know "boolean_option" is boolean. In my question, I don't know that boolean_option is a boolean or not. Code must recognize it. Not me. anyway thankyou.

Comment: You can wrap the `get` method in some other function, which would analyze the string you are getting from it and if it is one of 'boolean' values (True, False, Yes, No, etc) it returns boolean, and if not it returns string. But I wouldn't do it, you probably want to have your config options to have consistent types.

Comment: thanks @Nebril. I wonder that is there a built-in function for that.

Comment: There it is. Try using `literal_eval` from `ast` module.

Comment: Bulut Kare: if you found my answer useful, feel free to accept it (tick next to the answer).